# 'Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Rayon_Produits_Source' of the relationship Rayon_Produits' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I would like to add many items to EF in order to put them to database, but I have this error (given in the title).
I searched on internet, but I only found some ideas based on the fact that an item can't be added twice, which seems logical. but I took care of giving different Ids (Id is the property which is the key in the associated table), but it does not work, I still have this error. By now, I have no idea of what could go wrong.

here are the datas I am trying to push to the database, after the different model classes:

the biggest container : Supermarche

```
[DataContract]
public class Supermarche
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int SupermarcheId { set; get; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Magasin> Magasins { set; get; }


}
```

it contains some "Magasin":

```
[DataContract]
public class Magasin : ElementSupermarche
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int MagasinId { set; get; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Nom { set; get; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Rayon> Rayons { set; get; }


}
```

which contains itself some "Rayon":

```
[DataContract]
public class Rayon : ElementSupermarche
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int RayonId { set; get; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Nom { set; get; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<ProduitMagasin> Produits { set; get; }


}
```

which contains some "ProduitMagasin":

```
[DataContract]
public class ProduitMagasin : ElementSupermarche
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int ProduitMagasinId { set; get; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Nom { set; get; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Quantite { set; get; }

}
```

last, but not least, the filling part:

```
using (var ctx = new MarketContext("sqlserver"))
        {

            new MyDataInitializer().InitializeDatabase(ctx);

            var produitMagasin1 = new ProduitMagasin() { Nom = "Pommes", Quantite = 10 };
            var produitMagasin2 = new ProduitMagasin() { Nom = "Poires", Quantite = 5 };
            var rayon1 = new Rayon() { RayonId = 1, Nom = "Fruits & légumes", Produits = new ObservableCollection<ProduitMagasin>() { produitMagasin1, produitMagasin2 } };
            var produitMagasin5 = new ProduitMagasin() { Nom = "pizzas", Quantite = 4 };
            var produitMagasin6 = new ProduitMagasin() { Nom = "quiches", Quantite = 8 };
            var rayon3 = new Rayon() { RayonId = 2, Nom = "Surgelés", Produits = new ObservableCollection<ProduitMagasin>() { produitMagasin1, produitMagasin2 } };
            var magasin1 = new Magasin() { Nom = "Auchan", Rayons = new ObservableCollection<Rayon>() { rayon1, rayon3 } };

            ctx.SaveChanges();

            var produitMagasin3 = new ProduitMagasin() { Nom = "melons", Quantite = 13 };
            var produitMagasin4 = new ProduitMagasin() { Nom = "fraises", Quantite = 37 };
            var rayon2 = new Rayon() { RayonId = 3, Nom = "Fruits & légumes", Produits = new ObservableCollection<ProduitMagasin>() { produitMagasin3, produitMagasin4 } };
            var magasin2 = new Magasin() { Nom = "Carrefour", Rayons = new ObservableCollection<Rayon>() { rayon2 } };


            var supermarche1 = new Supermarche() { Magasins = new ObservableCollection<Magasin> { magasin1, magasin2 } };
            ctx.Supermarches.Add(supermarche1);

            ctx.SaveChanges();

        }
```

I don't think it is related, but here is the pull part which is in a WCF service and is executed right after the above code (in a different context, but there could be some time problem, maybe the computer reaches the pull part before having pushed the sample informations to the database:

```
using (var ctx2 = new MarketContext("sqlserver"))
        {
            ctx2.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var sm = ctx2.Supermarches
                .Include(s => s.Magasins.Select(mg => mg.Rayons.Select(r => r.Produits)))
                .First();

            return sm;
        }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

solved, the Rayon with RayonId=2 was containing the same Produits as the one with RayonId=1.